# How can I have a web components width and height be inherited by its children?

Tags: html, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

I have this button, that is a web component `bootstrap-social`. I would like to set its `display:inline` so that the button ends when its inner text ends. As you can see in the image its height and width are both `0`, I would like for the custom element's dimensions be the same as it's children's. How is this possible?

`<bootstrap-social style="display: inline;">` Has no effect.

[image]

Comment: Try `style="display: inline-block;"`?

Comment: @CletusW that worked, whoops! For some reason I forgot how to css.

Comment: @CletusW is this the same issue? What's going on here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295815/content-within-an-anchor-tag-isnt-switching-cursor-on-hover?noredirect=1#comment39430368_25295815

Comment: No, I just tried putting `display: inline-block` (and `block`, for that matter) on the elements in that question and it didn't help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `style="display: inline-block;"` instead. Custom elements by default are `display: inline;`.

**Note**: If you're using Shadow DOM, you can do this from within your shadow using `:host`:

```
#shadow-root
  <style>
    :host {
      display: inline-block;  /* or display: block; */
    }
  </style>
  <!-- ... -->
```

If you don't, users of your element will see `0px` by `0px` as the size, as shown in the OP's image, which is probably not desirable.