# <content> within an anchor tag isn't switching cursor on hover

Tags: html, polymer, web-component

*I should have specified that this is a polymer question and not native HTML.*

I have a template like this

```
<template>
  <a href="{{ href }}">
    <content></content>
  </a>
</template>
```

When I hover over the custom element my cursor is`cursor:text` and not `cursor:pointer`, this is an easy fix to apply cursor pointer, but I feel as if those kind of properties should be inherited. Is there any way to apply the `content` and inherit the a properties properly?

[Example on jsfiddle here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/qgso0onu/1/show/)

**Update: 1**

An even bigger issue with this is that you can't right-click and select copy-link either.

**Update: 2**

I kind of think I get it now, `<content>` isn't being passed a height or width, so the outer most element (the custom one) is height 0, width 0. So the anchor has no room to expand. Hence the cursor isn't switching.

tried, no luck

```
::content * {
  width:inherit;
  height:inherit;
}
```

**Update 3**

This kinda worked.

I had to give the anchor a `id=anchor` and use jQuery.

```
$(this.$.anchor).append($(this).html());
```

This won't import font-awesome icons for some reason, where  does.

Perhaps it's because it's not importing over the styles when I grab the HTML?

There's no error in the console either.

I dropped the  to font-awesome within the polymer template and it worked, which is kind of crappy. Need a better solution.

Comment: `<content>` is not a valid tag.

Comment: Well, you have no content to hover over; the tag is empty (and not closed). Try adding something to `<content>`: http://jsfiddle.net/cfalk/y8js701t/

Comment: @isherwood: The `hover` style should still be applied in most browsers even if it isn't a "valid tag." Unless you mean that OP isn't ending the tag -- in which case you are exactly right.

Comment: @CaseyFalk I did have a typo, I didn't close the `<content>` tag. But that didn't enable cursor pointer.

Comment: @ThomasReggi: There is nothing to make a link out of -- what exactly is supposed to have the `cursor:pointer`? All you are "linkifying" is an empty tag.

Comment: @isherwood in the world of polymer and web components it is.

Comment: Chrome won't even render it. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/n4y51zk6/

Comment: @isherwood: Chrome isn't rendering the **template** because you're never using it in the Fiddle. It renders `<content>` fine; see the JSFiddle in my first comment. :) (For more: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/)

Comment: Right you are. You should put your answer in an answer. :-)

Comment: Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/qgso0onu/1/ here's the example where the link works but the cursor doesn't change http://fiddle.jshell.net/qgso0onu/1/show/

Comment: If you don't mind not being able to highlight or click the stuff behind the `a`, you could try moving `content` outside `a`, then applying `layout fit` attributes to `<a>`

Comment: Unrelated, but your closing `<polymer-element>` tag should go after the closing `</script>` tag, not after your usage of the element. And you shouldn't need `shim-shadowdom` on your style tag inside a `<polymer-element>`. Not sure why you're seeing this problem, though. I even tried applying `display: inline-block;` to the `<anchor-query>`, `<a>`, and `<content>` (http://fiddle.jshell.net/dg3fry4q/) but that didn't help.

Comment: This looks to be a bug with native Shadow DOM (unrelated to Polymer). [This jsbin](http://jsbin.com/mezuhikuxewa/1/edit?html,js,output) exhibits the same behavior without Polymer or the platform.js polyfills on Chrome 36.

Comment: I've asked this question on the [polymer-dev forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/polymer-dev/eGv_oTUQZ7o/7t_ip4WtGikJ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is a bug](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/polymer-dev/eGv_oTUQZ7o/r5zFHeBljaEJ) with Chrome's current implementation of Shadow DOM that will be fixed in Chrome 37.

Answer (score 0):

**You have nothing to make a link out of; you're "linkifying" an empty block.**

If you give `<content>` some innards, you'll see the inherited style:

```
<template>
  <a href="{{ href }}">
    <content> Here is a link. </content>
  </a>
</template>
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cfalk/y8js701t/)

Comment: Polymer uses `<content>` to take the guts of a custom element and bring it within the element. In the jsfiddle I posted you can see there's an img tag within the custom element and it's being imported via the `<content>` tag within the `<template>`. It's just not inheriting the `<a>` parent's cursor, because in reality it's not really nested within it.

Comment: So there is no parent anchor tag. Is this a misuse of Polymer?

Comment: @ThomasReggi: Updating... Didn't realize the problem was specific to Polymer since it is never mentioned in the question (and only discretely in the tags). My bad.

Comment: Not a problem! Thanks for trying @CaseyFalk!

Comment: Still looking... Judging by Devtools, it looks like Chrome isn't applying the Polymer templating at all but instead the link happens to be working because the `href` attribute is set on the `anchor-query`.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how you're actually using this element, but http://jsbin.com/qaqigizajuvi/1/edit is a simple example of how to make at least what I think you're trying to achieve, work.

If you're using `{{ name }}` macros, you'll need to declare attributes for each name that you use. There's also no point in a `<content>` block if you just want a linktext: use another attribute macro in your definition:

```
<polymer-element name="monkey-test" attributes="href label" noscript>
  <template>
    <a href="{{ href }}">{{ label }}</a>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

and then instantiate it as either:

```
<monkey-test href="http://example.org" label="tadah"></monkey-test>
```

or set up a `<monkey-test>` element and then set its href and label attributes via JavaScript using `e.href=...` and `e.label=...` or `e.setAttribute(name, value)`

note that the `noscript` attribute is used here because there's no explicit script block with a `new Polymer('monkey-test', { ... })` call. If we want a more complex element, we can't get away with noscript.

Comment: This doesn't help. I don't want just linktext. I want the same  support that `<a>` tags have. Drop a child `<img>` or any element. The component I created takes any number of variable attributes, so I can't pass them within `attributes`. This shouldn't conflict with the `<content>` within the custom element. I published what I have here, even though the bug still exists. https://github.com/reggi/polymer-anchor-query

Comment: Interesting. Looks like a bug in Polymer, worth filing over at https://github.com/polymer/customelements/issues (http://jsbin.com/qaqigizajuvi/2/edit serving as a minimal example of the bug)

Comment: [Here's](http://jsbin.com/qaqigizajuvi/6/edit?html,output) an even further reduced test case that shows how text in the Shadow DOM gets linkified even in the same `<a>` tag.